# Proof Question on Open Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

I was reading this post  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631585/a-finite-dimensional-representation-of-a-totally-disconnected-group-is-continuou) . Why is it sufficient to say that $\ker(\pi)$ contains an open subgroup to conclude that $\ker(\pi)$ is an open subgroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be an open subgroup contained in $G=\ker(\pi)$. Then we can find an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq H$ containing the identity. Then $$G=\bigcup_{g\in G}Ug,$$ and is open.