# Why are finite-dimensional representations smooth?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $(\pi, V)$ a continuous representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ into a *finite-dimensional vector space*. I want to understand why $\pi$ is necessarily smooth (and why it is not the case anymore when the dimension is infinite). I found an argument I do not understand, I am trying to elaborate here.

By definition have a continuous map $\pi : GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p) \to GL(\mathbb{C}^n)$. We know $ker(\pi) = \pi^{-1}(I_n)$ whezre $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$.

If $R$ is a small open neighborhood of $I_n$, then $\pi^{-1}(R)$ is an open set (by continuity). It hence contain qn open set $N$, and this can be taken to be a normal subgroup (why is that so? is that particular to $GL_n$?).

For $R$ sufficiently small, $\chi(N) \subset R$ should be $\{I_n\}$ because there is no arbitrarily small subgroup in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (is that true only for finite dimensions?), finishing the proof.

So that altogether, I have these two questions in the argument above:

- why can we take open normal subgroups as a basis of neighborhood of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$? Is that characteristic of the $p$-adic or of the finite-dimension or of $GL_n$?
- why is there no arbitrarily small sungroups? Is that characteristic of the $p$-adic or of the finite-dimension or of $GL_n$?

Comment: The "no small subgroups" aspect is about the *complex* group ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf C)$.  It means there's a neighborhood of the identity in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf C)$ that contains no subgroup other than the trivial subgroup.  Do you see why this is true when $n = 1$: $\mathbf C^\times$ has a neighborhood of $1$ containing no nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbf C^\times$?

Comment: The basis of open (normal) subgroups is an aspect of the $p$-*adic* group ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf Q_p)$.  Think about the open subsets $I_n + p^m{\rm M}_n(\mathbf Z_p)$ for all positive integers $m$; they shrink to $\{I_n\}$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for the comments. For $\mathbb{C}^\times$, I am thinking of it as exponentiating additive groups. In $\mathbb{R}$ they are lattices or dense. But there is no dense ones for $\mathbb{C}^\times$? (I suppose it is for this precise fact that the finite dimension is needed?)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631585/a-finite-dimensional-representation-of-a-totally-disconnected-group-is-continuou?rq=1